# Incrementing values within methods?

Tags: java, oop, methods

So for this program I don't understand why times is still 0 . Why is count able to increment but times is not? I thought changing the parameter name would change this but I was wrong. Does this have to do with the scope of variables or something entirely different? Thanks1

```
1  public class Test {
2    public static void main(String[] args) {
3      Count myCount = new Count();
4      int times = 0;
5      for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
6        increment(myCount, times);
7      System.out.println("count is " + myCount.count);
8      System.out.println("times is " + times);
9    }
10
11   public static void increment(Count c, int times) {
12     c.count++;
13     times++;
14   }
15 }


1  public class Count {
2    public int count;
3    public Count(int c) {
4      count = c;
5    }
6    public Count() {
7      count = 1;
8    }
  }
```

Comment: declare **times** out of main method

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value

Comment: Read about call by value. Also you are shadowing your member field (by re-using the name *times* as method parameter name). Both these things come together thus giving the "strange" results.

Comment: @GhostCat What member field?

Comment: @shmosel Ah sorry, the *local* variable in the main method. It was a bit late when I wrote that comment.